# MYSQL SELECT only one column from all rows in table

Tags: mysql, sql

I need to select all values from all rows by one column in my table. I have

```
ID       TAGS
1        girls, womens, cars
2        girls, world, flowers
3        weapons, cars, boys
```

so after SQL I should get an array:

```
array('girls', 'womens', 'cars', 'girls', 'world', 'flowers', 'weapons', 'cars', 'boys')
```

so how my sql should look like?

Comment: This is not possible if you have a multi valued field. there's a bit of post processing you need to do with your query result.

Comment: The OP did not prohibit the use of post-processing!

Comment: how the query should look like for getting all tags from all rows? after then i think I could dekete similar values from array

Comment: Are there always three tags?

Comment: no, there can be 100 keywords. It be enough for me just get all values, similar too

Comment: The amended question can be solved with `SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(tags SEPARATOR ' ') FROm tags;`

Answer (score 5):

### Never, never, never store multiple values in one column.

Like you see now this will only give you headaches. Normalize your table.

```
USER_ID  TAG
1        girls
1        women
1        cars
2        girls
...
```

After that you could select your desired result like this

```
select group_concat(distinct tag)
from your_table
```

Comment: If you're using wordpress or similar, then I'm afraid it's pretty much unavoidable.

Comment: this is not an option, becouse all actions is in my news table, where is columns: id, name, url, tags. So I can't make other table for tags

Answer (score 0):

Use [GROUP_CONCAT()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat). A similar answer is already here [MySQL DISTINCT on a GROUP_CONCAT()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3083499/mysql-distinct-on-a-group-concat).

Answer (score 0):

I can atleast give a sample solution:

1. use Cursor or something to traverse through each row of data
2. split the data (there are couple of split example found in internet) [sample example, Split string in SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2647/split-string-in-sql)
3. put the value in a temp table
4. finally select distinct from the table

someone can put these example and make a solution.