# Set a DISTINCT while or not a specific value included in MySQL.

Tags: php, mysql, sql, distinct

I want to get values with DISTINCT but it has to include a spesific value only once ever it hasn't got.
For example DISTINCT gets 
`"John, Gabriel, Alisia, George"` so the `"Johann"` must added but,
if DISTINCT already returns with "Johann" like 
`"John, Gabriel, Alisia, George, Johann"` so no need to add again.
I cant figure my SQL.
using MySQL and PHP.

Comment: Can you post sample data and desired results.  Having a difficult time understanding your question.

Comment: Your question is not clear to me, please post sample data and the actual query, that you run.

Comment: I need a result set that always includes a value whenever it never recorded to table. Bu if it also between the result no need to add again.

Comment: That's what the DISTINCT keyword does. Please edit your question and put the current query you're u sing.

Comment: I cant figure out any query at the moment. DISTINCT only filter what has table got. I want to return a result set which includes a spesific value in every condition whether DISTINCT gets or not. But if this spesific value returned between the result set with DISTINCT, no need to add it again.

Comment: Also my data set isn't suitable to run this query yet. I am planning to modify it if there construct the sql :/

Answer (score -1):

If you're doing a GROUP_CONCAT then you can do a DISTINCT one, such as:

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT name) FROM some_table;
```

See also: [MySQL DISTINCT on a GROUP_CONCAT()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3083499/mysql-distinct-on-a-group-concat)