# PHP array is not printing outside foreach loop

Tags: php, arrays, api, sms

I am working on this script main function is to take a numbers from database with commas and use it inside curl to send a sms with api.

```
if(isset($_POST['getnumber']))

    {
        $matchid2 = $_POST['matchid2'];
        //connect db
        require_once __DIR__ . '/../db_connect.php';
        $db = new DB_CONNECT();
        $con = $db->connect();        
        $results = $con->query("SELECT DISTINCT ur.mobile FROM matchmst mst INNER JOIN matchdetail dtl on mst.matchid=dtl.matchid INNER JOIN user ur on ur.userid=dtl.userid WHERE mst.matchid = '$matchid2'");
        // look through query
        $datas = array();

        while($row = $results->fetch_assoc()){
                $datas[] = $row;                                
            }

        foreach ($datas as $data) {
            $mobiles = $data['mobile'].",";
        }

    }
```

When i tried to echo this in html i am only getting one value from array i.e. 84*******4, and blank
but i want to print complete row of that nubers in html

```
<div class="form-group">
        <?php echo '<label for="msg">'.$mobiles.'</label>'; ?>

</div>
```

So how can i solve this pelase help.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: You could try using `GROUP_CONCAT()` in your SQL to retrieve the value directly from your SQL (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3083499/mysql-distinct-on-a-group-concat).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would be easier to build the string whilst reading the data than to manipulate it in more loops...

```
    $results = $con->query("SELECT DISTINCT ur.mobile FROM matchmst mst INNER JOIN matchdetail dtl on mst.matchid=dtl.matchid INNER JOIN user ur on ur.userid=dtl.userid WHERE mst.matchid = '$matchid2'");
    // look through query
    $mobiles = "";

    while($row = $results->fetch_assoc()){
            $mobiles .= $row['mobile'] . ",";                                
    }
    // Remove trailing , if needed
    $mobiles = substr($mobiles, 0, -1);
```

You should also look at using prepared statements to improve security of your site.

Comment: if OP want only mobile number  then he need to do `fecth_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC)` to get all numbers at-once and use `implode()` to show it. then no need of `while` as well as `foreach()`

Comment: @AnantSingh---AlivetoDie - `fetch_all()` internally uses a loop, `implode()` uses another loop, `array_column()` uses another loop.  Just because it is 1 command it doesn't mean that it is more efficient.  Also you create 2 new arrays on top of all the arrays for each row and use more memory than just using 1 loop.