# group_concat works incorrect on multiple join

Tags: mysql, sql, join, select, aggregate-functions

I have a problem with building select request with joining and concatenation data from 3 tables.

First table **entity** has ids of some entities with their authors:

| id | author |
| --- | --- |
| 11 | "John" |
| 12 | "Mike" |
| 13 | "Kevin" |

2nd and 3rd tables have sections and files related to this entities, one row for each. Count of sections and files can be different for any entity.

**file**:

| id | entity_id | file_name |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 11 | file1 |
| 2 | 12 | file1 |
| 3 | 12 | file2 |
| 4 | 12 | file3 |
| 5 | 13 | file4 |
| 6 | 13 | file5 |
| 7 | 13 | file6 |

**section** (also some entities can be w/o sections like 12 in this example):

| id | entity_id | section_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 11 | 1001 |
| 2 | 11 | 1002 |
| 3 | 13 | 1003 |

I need to select all data from entities table joining related sections and files as comma-separated strings. For this purpose I've created following request:

```
SELECT 
    entity.id, 
    entity.author, 
    group_concat(section.section_id) section_ids, 
    group_concat(file.file_name) files 
FROM entity
LEFT JOIN file ON entity.id = file.entity_id
LEFT JOIN section ON entity.id = section.entity_id
group by entity.id;
```

I'm expecting to get following result:

| id | author | files | section_ids |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 11 | "John" | file1 | 1001,1002 |
| 12 | "Mike" | file1,file2,file3 | null |
| 13 | "Kevin" | file4,file5,file6 | 1003 |

But actually I'm getting this one:

| id | author | files | section_ids |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 11 | "John" | file1,file1 | 1001,1002 |
| 12 | "Mike" | file1,file2,file3 | null |
| 13 | "Kevin" | file4,file5,file6 | 1003,1003,1003 |

Looks like files are duplicated where entity has multiple sections and sections are duplicated when entity has multiple files.
I tried to play with different types of join (inner/outher, right/left) but didn't find any solution. Please help me to fix this query.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is when you have multiple matchs in both tables for a given entity: the joins multiply the rows, and the results of the aggregates are wrong.

I would recommend pre-aggregation. A couple of subqueries should do the job just fine:

```
select e.id, e.author, 
    (select group_concat(f.file_name) from file f where f.entity_id = e.id) as files_names
    (select group_concat(s.section_id) from section s where s.entity_id = e.id) as section_ids
from entity e
```

Answer (score 0):

You are joining against two different dimensions, resulting in a Cartesian product. The simplest adjustment to your query is DISTINCT:

```
SELECT e.id, e.author, 
      group_concat(distinct s.section_id) as section_ids, 
      group_concat(f.file_name) as files 
FROM entity e LEFT JOIN
     file f
     ON e.id = f.entity_id LEFT JOIN
     section s
     ON e.id = s.entity_id
group by e.id;
```

However, for performance, I would recommend the approach that GMB suggests.

Comment: So you opened the question I closed as duplicate and posted as your answer the answer of the duplicate link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3083499/mysql-distinct-on-a-group-concat ?

Comment: I downvoted your answer because it is exactly the same as the answers in the duplicate link and in order to post it you opened a closed question although you knew that the question is a duplicate.